# Batch processing layouts with several shapefiles based on master layout

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I'm trying to batch some layouts based on a master layout through the python console in QGIS. Basically, what I'm trying is to generate a layout like the one below and print a *.png of the layout.

[image]

I have written a script in the python console looping through some 21 different *.shp files using the same master layout as basis. However, the imported shape files sort of overwrite the map items of the master layout and the output of the code is for instance a map like this very much simple one, only containing the *.shp file basically:

[image]

My code is pasted below, which I hope I could get some help with:

```
%%

from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayout, QgsLayoutItemMap, QgsLayoutExporter
import os

# List of shapefile file names
files = ["NS1(NS2).1.1", "NS1(NS2).1.2", "NS1(NS3).1.1", "NS1(NS3).1.2", "NS1(NS3).1.3", "NS1(NS2).2.1", "NS1(NS2).2.2",
         "NS1(NS2).2.3", "NS1(NS3).2.1", "NS1(NS3).2.2", "NS1(NS3).2.3", "NS1(NS2).3.1", "NS1(NS2).3.2", "NS1(NS3).3.1",
         "NS1(NS3).3.2", "NS1(NS2).4.1", "NS1(NS2).4.2", "NS1(NS2).4.3", "NS1(NS3).4.1", "NS1(NS3).4.2", "NS1(NS3).4.3"]

# Directory containing shapefiles
dir_shp = 'O:\\A245000\\A245595\\40-Calculations\\MIKE21\\PP\\Hs_Normalized_15MW_Normal\\Results'

# Paths to the shapefiles
shapefile_paths = [os.path.join(dir_shp, "Hs_factor_15MW_Normal_" + file + ".shp") for file in files]

# Path to the .qml style files
style_file = 'C:\\Users\\ASHN\\COWI\\A245595 - MV af Mere Havvind - Documents\\60-WorkInProgress\\50-QGIS\\WorkingFolder\\Layouts\\Hs_factor_style.qml'

# Load the master layout by name
master_layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Hs_factor_master_v1')

if master_layout is None:
    print("Master layout not found.")
else:
    print("Master layout found.")

    # Find the map item in the master layout
    map_frame = None
    for item in master_layout.items():
        if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
            map_frame = item
            break

    if map_frame is not None:
        # Iterate through shapefile_paths and update the map frame in the master layout
        for shapefile_path in shapefile_paths:
            # Clone the master layout
            new_layout = master_layout.clone()
            new_layout.setName(f'Layout_{os.path.basename(shapefile_path)}')

            # Find the map item in the cloned layout
            map_frame = None
            for item in new_layout.items():
                if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
                    map_frame = item
                    break

            if map_frame is not None:
                # Add the shapefile as a vector layer to the cloned layout
                vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile_path, 'LayerNameXX', 'ogr')
                if vector_layer.isValid():
                    vector_layer.loadNamedStyle(style_file)
                    map_frame.setLayers([vector_layer])
                    print(f"Updated layer {vector_layer.name()} in the map frame.")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to load layer from {shapefile_path}")

                # Add the cloned layout to the QgsProject's layout manager
                QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().addLayout(new_layout)

                # Export the layout to PNG format
                output_path = f'C:\\Users\\ASHN\\COWI\\A245595 - MV af Mere Havvind - Documents\\60-WorkInProgress\\50-QGIS\\WorkingFolder\\Layouts\\{os.path.basename(shapefile_path).replace(".shp", "")}_layout.png'
                exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(new_layout)
                exporter.exportToImage(output_path, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())

                # Print a message indicating that the layout is created
                print('Layout created for:', output_path)
            else:
                print("Map frame not found in the cloned layout.")
    else:
        print("Map frame not found in the master layout.")

%%
```

Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: In this line: `map_frame.setLayers([vector_layer])` you are setting only the one vector layer to the layout map.